# MSI installer overwrites file that is defined as

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a setup project. With this settings:

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
                  AllowDowngrades="no"
                  DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of MyProg SQL is already installed." />
```

I have a single target folder. In this folder there might be an existing MyINI.INI File. I added a new file to my setup script that should be added if it doesn't exist, but never overwritten if it exists. So I added this entry to my project.

```
  <Component Id="INI" Guid="" NeverOverwrite="yes">
    <File Name="MyINI.ini" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

I have a test situation and an existent INI file. The installer overwrites the file as seen in the logs.

```
MSI (s) (C4:88) [08:07:31:314]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=mtf8frk3.ini|MyINI.ini,SourceCabKey=MyINI.ini,DestName=MyINI.ini,Attributes=512,FileSize=1297,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=1245125278,HashPart2=-97536650,HashPart3=1077411022,HashPart4=1055412336,,)
MSI (s) (C4:88) [08:07:31:314]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\AG-VIP SQL\AG-VIP Job Scheduler Service\MyINI.ini; Overwrite;  Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned and unmodified - hash doesn't match source file
MSI (s) (C4:88) [08:07:31:314]: Source for file 'MyINI.ini' is compressed
```

Why? How can I prevent that any overwrite of an existing file happens?

**EDIT:**
In making the component Permanent and giving it a GUID, it work now.

```
  <Component Id="INI" Guid="{AAA7205E-FFC9-4848-9057-F1B3F343E3A0}" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
        <File Name="AGVIPJobScheduler.ini" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
```

**But now my question: Why?**